# nspredicate escaping url

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

When using an NSPredicate for an NSFetchRequest and searching for a URL is there a need to escape "/"?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(url == %@) , aURL];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this as i assume aURL is string:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(url == %@") , aURL];
```

Also try like this:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY url  like '%@'" , aURL];
```